# How to apply position to nodes after filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xpath, system.xml

```
<AppXmlLogWritter>
  <LogData>
    <LogID>235820130202134128634953894887814709273</LogID>
    <LogDateTime>20130102134128</LogDateTime>
    <LogType>Warning</LogType>
    <LogFlag>PACSFlag</LogFlag>
    <LogApplication>PACSLogApplication</LogApplication>
    <LogModule>PACSLogModule</LogModule>
    <LogLocation>PACSLogLocation</LogLocation>
    <LogText>PACSLogText</LogText>
  </LogData>
  <LogData>
    <LogID>2358201302021341286349538948878147093861</LogID>
    <LogDateTime>20130202134128</LogDateTime>
    <LogType>Error</LogType>
    <LogFlag>PACSFlag</LogFlag>
    <LogApplication>PACSLogApplication</LogApplication>
    <LogModule>PACSLogModule</LogModule>
    <LogLocation>PACSLogLocation</LogLocation>
    <LogText>PACSLogText</LogText>
  </LogData>
</AppXmlLogWritter>
```

**XpathQuery**

```
/AppXmlLogWritter/LogData[LogApplication/text()[starts-with(. , 'P')]and position()>='1' and position()<='3']

**Before Filter**
<Node 1> Position 1
<Node 2> Position 2
<Node 3> Position 3
<Node 4> Position 4
<Node 5> Position 5
<Node 6> Position 6   

 **After Filter**
<Node 2> Position 2
<Node 5> Position 5
<Node 6> Position 6
```

See in above list of nodes Before filter i have 6 nodes but when i filter i am getting three nodes
so i write query for that position()>='1' and position()<='3  but result getting only 1 node
In sql there is rownumber condition after filter rownumber is apply to all rows but in xml how can i achieve. I am not using LINQ to XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parentheses:

```
(/AppXmlLogWritter/LogData[LogApplication[starts-with(. , 'P')]])[position()<=3]
```

If you put the position test inside the `LogData` predicate then it applies just to that location step and will restrict the match to those `LogData` elements that are the first, second or third `LogData` child of their respective parent elements. With the parentheses you're constructing an initial node set (of all the `LogData` elements whose `LogApplication` starts with P) and then selecting the first three nodes *from that set* in document order.

Comment: @Means you need to understand both forms, they mean different things and you need to choose the appropriate one for each situation. For example `/foo/bar[1]` selects the first `bar` from inside each `foo`, whereas `(/foo/bar)[1]` selects just one `bar` (which would be the first bar child of the first foo-that-has-any-bars).  Both are useful in different circumstances.  I think of it in terms of "`[]` binds tighter than `/`" (in the same way that multiplication binds tighter than addition in maths).